# conditional template to load external css in polymer

Tags: css, external, polymer, web-component

Hi I'm trying to load conditionlly an external css file in my polymer but is not working 
the code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-polymer-component" attributes="query">
  <template>
    <template if="{{condition}}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="my-polymer-component.css"/>
    </template>
    <template if="{{condition}}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="my-polymer-component2.css"/>
    </template>
    <section class="container">
          <div class="headerImportText">
            <span>
              hello world
            </span>
          </div>
    <section>
  <template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I need to changed the UI of the component by the condition.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot do declarative conditional CSS loading in the template,
you must do your conditional CSS loading programmatically.

Here you have a sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/8Oavqpbh8eJTTKLw13bL?p=preview

Relevant part of the code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-polymer-component" attributes="condition">
  <template>
    <h1>Condition: {{condition}}</h1>
    <section class="container">
        <content> </content>
    </section>
  </template>
  <script>
      Polymer({
        domReady: function() {
          var fileref=document.createElement("link")
          fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
          fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
          fileref.setAttribute("href", this.condition+".css")
          console.log(fileref)
          this.appendChild(fileref)
          console.log("domReady!")

        }
      });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<h1>Here you have a sample</h1>
<my-polymer-component condition="a">
</my-polymer-component>
```

Hope it helps!